# What does vim consider a paragragh?

Tags: cursor-motions, whitespace

Suppose I have the following piece of code through which I would like to navigate

```
===>Cursor is here and when I press {
    SomeTest
    {
       line1
       line2
       line3

       line4
            =====>it ends up here
       line 5
    }
   ====>Cursor should end up here
```

I would like the cursor which is on top of `SomeTest` statement to go at the end of the code paragraph. Normally I would use `{` and `}` to skip to the next paragraph. However the presence of blank lines before line4 and line 5 make this technique fail.

Why does having a single blank line above and below line 4 move the cursor there. What can I do to fix this ? What does Vim consider a paragraph ? I know I could use `]}`to go the ending or beginning if I am inside the function. What I would like to do is jump through the function from top to the bottom and not going inside the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to move to the next section:

```
]]
```

Documentation:

```
:h paragraph
A paragraph begins after each empty line, and also at each of a set of
paragraph macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the 'paragraphs' option. 

:h section
A section begins after a form-feed (<C-L>) in the first column and at each of
a set of section macros, specified by the pairs of characters in the
'sections' option.
```